# Fire Department 3 - ports and multiplayer

Tags: technical-issues, fire-department-3

a friend of mine recently asked me if I would like to play "**Fire Department 3**" with him. There is an issue however, since none of us has a static IP, so we can't connect to each other just by typing our adresses ingame.

I figured out that we would need to use either VPN or port forwarding. Since creating VPN didn't work out well, we decided to give the port forwarding a try. However, this game doesn't have this information in its manual and the company is long gone.

I am looking for either ports I would need to forward or some experience with setting up the multiplayer.

Comment: port forwarding won't help either, you need a static IP.

Comment: Why not set static IP's? It's pretty simple.

Comment: I guess I messed the problem up a bit - I thought that I would have to forward ports on my router so that he could connect to me. Static/dynamic IP doesn't change much in this regard I guess?